# Open Source Website Deployed with Travis-CI

Tags: travis-ci

This is more of a question of licensing, I was just wondering this.  With Travis, does the "Free" account allow you to compile / publish open source Jekyll sites, that being public repositories on GitHub with all the site source code in, but the site be advertising products that are not "open source"?

For example, let's say I made a bunch of mobile apps, and wanted to advertise them on my website, and I choose Jekyll and Travis-CI, the site would have links to the relevant app stores where you can buy the app, but the apps themselves are not open source.

Is that within the legal standings?

Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a great questions. Essentially we determine whether your repository needs to be built using http://travis-ci.com or http://travis-ci.org based on whether the repository is public or private.

So as long as the repository itself is public, you're free to build it on http://travis-ci.org/

Does that clear things up?

Comment: Fantastico! :) yup this certainly clears things up. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019, the information provided by `solarce` is now incorrect. Please use [travis-ci.com](https://travis-ci.com) regardless of your repository being public or private. For more information, please read [this blog post](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/migrate/open-source-on-travis-ci-com).